# FTGL linking to Visual studio 2022 (x86) using VCPKG C++

Tags: visual-studio, static-linking, vcpkg, ftgl

i'm attempting to link FTGL using these install commands:

```
./vcpkg install glfw3:x86-windows-static
./vcpkg install freetype:x86-windows-static
./vcpkg install ftgl:x86-windows-static
```

here are the settings in VS:

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgrqS.png)

I'm getting these errors from the debugger:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '??0FTPoint@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall FTPoint::FTPoint(void))' defined in 'ftgld.lib(FTFont.cpp.obj)' is imported by 'window.obj' in function '"public: void __thiscall Text::update(void)" (?update@Text@@QAEXXZ)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '??0FTPoint@@QAE@NNN@Z (public: __thiscall FTPoint::FTPoint(double,double,double))' defined in 'ftgld.lib(FTFont.cpp.obj)' is imported by 'window.obj' in function '"public: void __thiscall Text::update(void)" (?update@Text@@QAEXXZ)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '??0FTTextureFont@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall FTTextureFont::FTTextureFont(char const *))' defined in 'ftgld.lib(FTTextureFont.cpp.obj)' is imported by 'window.obj' in function '"public: __thiscall Text::Text(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct Vector_2D,int,struct Color_RGB,double,bool)" (??0Text@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0UVector_2D@@HUColor_RGB@@N_N@Z)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '??1FTTextureFont@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall FTTextureFont::~FTTextureFont(void))' defined in 'ftgld.lib(FTTextureFont.cpp.obj)' is imported by 'window.obj' in function '"public: virtual void * __thiscall FTTextureFont::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GFTTextureFont@@UAEPAXI@Z)'
1>mpg123.lib(compat.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathCombineW@12 referenced in function _INT123_compat_catpath
1>mpg123.lib(compat.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathIsRelativeW@4 referenced in function _wpath_need_elongation
1>mpg123.lib(compat.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathIsUNCW@4 referenced in function _wlongpath
```

here are the release errors:

```
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual class FTGlyph * __thiscall FTTextureFont::MakeGlyph(struct FT_GlyphSlotRec_ *)" (__imp_?MakeGlyph@FTTextureFont@@MAEPAVFTGlyph@@PAUFT_GlyphSlotRec_@@@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FTTextureFont::~FTTextureFont(void)" (__imp_??1FTTextureFont@@UAE@XZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FTTextureFont::FTTextureFont(char const *)" (__imp_??0FTTextureFont@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual int __thiscall FTFont::Error(void)const " (__imp_?Error@FTFont@@UBEHXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FTPoint __thiscall FTFont::Render(char const *,int,class FTPoint,class FTPoint,int)" (__imp_?Render@FTFont@@UAE?AVFTPoint@@PBDHV2@1H@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FTPoint __thiscall FTFont::Render(wchar_t const *,int,class FTPoint,class FTPoint,int)" (__imp_?Render@FTFont@@UAE?AVFTPoint@@PB_WHV2@1H@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual float __thiscall FTFont::Advance(char const *,int,class FTPoint)" (__imp_?Advance@FTFont@@UAEMPBDHVFTPoint@@@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual float __thiscall FTFont::Advance(wchar_t const *,int,class FTPoint)" (__imp_?Advance@FTFont@@UAEMPB_WHVFTPoint@@@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FTBBox __thiscall FTFont::BBox(char const *,int,class FTPoint,class FTPoint)" (__imp_?BBox@FTFont@@UAE?AVFTBBox@@PBDHVFTPoint@@1@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FTBBox __thiscall FTFont::BBox(wchar_t const *,int,class FTPoint,class FTPoint)" (__imp_?BBox@FTFont@@UAE?AVFTBBox@@PB_WHVFTPoint@@1@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual float __thiscall FTFont::LineHeight(void)const " (__imp_?LineHeight@FTFont@@UBEMXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual float __thiscall FTFont::Descender(void)const " (__imp_?Descender@FTFont@@UBEMXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual float __thiscall FTFont::Ascender(void)const " (__imp_?Ascender@FTFont@@UBEMXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FTFont::UseDisplayList(bool)" (__imp_?UseDisplayList@FTFont@@UAEX_N@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FTFont::Outset(float)" (__imp_?Outset@FTFont@@UAEXM@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FTFont::Outset(float,float)" (__imp_?Outset@FTFont@@UAEXMM@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FTFont::Depth(float)" (__imp_?Depth@FTFont@@UAEXM@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall FTFont::FaceSize(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_?FaceSize@FTFont@@UAE_NII@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall FTFont::FaceSize(void)const " (__imp_?FaceSize@FTFont@@UBEIXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual enum FT_Encoding_ * __thiscall FTFont::CharMapList(void)" (__imp_?CharMapList@FTFont@@UAEPAW4FT_Encoding_@@XZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall FTFont::CharMapCount(void)const " (__imp_?CharMapCount@FTFont@@UBEIXZ)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall FTFont::CharMap(enum FT_Encoding_)" (__imp_?CharMap@FTFont@@UAE_NW4FT_Encoding_@@@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FTFont::GlyphLoadFlags(int)" (__imp_?GlyphLoadFlags@FTFont@@UAEXH@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall FTFont::Attach(char const *)" (__imp_?Attach@FTFont@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall FTFont::Attach(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (__imp_?Attach@FTFont@@UAE_NPBEI@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FTPoint::FTPoint(double,double,double)" (__imp_??0FTPoint@@QAE@NNN@Z)
1>window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FTPoint::FTPoint(void)" (__imp_??0FTPoint@@QAE@XZ)
```

Comment: NEVERMIND: I GOT FTGL working on release using: #define FTGL_LIBRARY_STATIC